# when is initialization for variables required in C programming

Tags: c, variables

I am a beginner at C programming, in this code I wrote, the compiler insists that I put initial values for the variables `ch2`, and `ch3`.
what confuses me is why is that needed in this instance, when would I be in need of initializing values for variables, and when wouldn't I need to (in general)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch, ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0, ch3 = 0;
    while (1) {
        ch = _getche();
        ch1 = ch2;
        ch2 = ch3;
        ch3 = ch;
        if (ch1 == 'h' && ch2 == 'e' && ch3 == 'y') {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nHello !");
}
```

Comment: go through "c storage classes". It'll help you understand scope and lifetime of a variable. In your case ch1, ch2, ch3 are automatic variables which gets initialized to some garbage value/undefined value by default.

Comment: Your compiler complains about initial values because you are using them uninitialized in your first iteration. Otherwise, there's no general rule to initialize variables with any values when you define them. Just make sure you don't use them uninitialized.

Comment: @Lundin He asked why his compiler "forces" him to initialize (not in the code OP posted).

Comment: The compiler should not *force* you to initialize `ch1`. Which compiler do you use? What command line options are passed?

Comment: error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'ch2' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'ch3' used
yea sorry i was mistaken it wasn't complaining about ch1 uninitialized
but still why should he ask me to initialize those significantly?
@chqrlie

Comment: @MohamedZiad: read my answer: `ch2` and `ch3` are read in the loop. They must have an initial value for the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @chqrlie yeah thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only constraint in C is objects must be initialized before you can read their value.

Global objects and local objects with `static` storage class are initialized automatically when the process is started, either from the explicit initializer you wrote in the source code in their definition, or to their zero value (and that of all of their members and elements for aggregates) if no initializer is present at the definition point in the source code. The zero value is `0` for numeric and character types and `NULL` for pointers. The first member of unions is initialized to its zero value.

Other local objects are not initialized by default, so you must either provide an initalizer at the point of definition or store a value into them before you read their value.

In your example, in the `while` loop, the values of `ch2` and `ch3` are read before they are written to. These must be initialized before the loop, but a value is stored into `ch` and `ch1` before the `if`, so they do not need to be initialized before the loop.  You could safely remove the initializer for `ch1`.

The reason the compiler warns you to initialize `ch2` and `ch3` is to avoid undefined behavior during the first iteration of the loop.  If by chance uninitialized `ch2` had the value `'h'` and uninitialized `ch3` had the value `'e'` before the first iteration, just hitting `y` would suffice to break from the loop.

I urge you to compile your code with warnings enabled to allow the compiler to diagnose potential uses of uninitialized variables.  It is not perfect, there can be both false positives and false negatives, but the diagnostics are usually very useful to avoid silly mistakes leading to undefined behavior.

It does not hurt to initialize all local variables to a constant. The compilers are usually smart enough to remove redundant stores, ie: they do not generate code for storing values to non `volatile` local variables that are not used before either receiving another value or going out of scope.

Note that your code can be simplified with one less variable this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch = 0, ch1 = 0, ch2;
    for (;;) {
        ch2 = ch1;
        ch1 = ch;
        ch = _getche();
        if (ch2 == 'h' && ch1 == 'e' && ch == 'y') {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\nHello !\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when would i be in need of initializing values for variables ,and when wouldn't i need to (in general)?

There may be some special occasion when a variable is automatically initialised to zero (eg., static global variable).

But as a rule of thumb, it's always good practice (and no harm) to initialise all variables before usage.

So in your case, initialise them all:

```
int ch = 0, ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0, ch3 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The really interesting question is **when is initialization for variables in C**.

In the **uninitialize** variables are guaranteed to be initialized to zero(external and static variables ), **auto** and **register** variables have **undefined** (i.e., garbage) initial values.

In effect, initialization of **auto** variables are just shorthand for assignment statements. Which form to prefer is largely a matter of taste. We have generally used explicit assignments, because initializers in declarations are harder to see and further away from the point of use.

For more information, then read [storage class in C](http://cs-fundamentals.com/c-programming/storage-classes-in-c-and-storage-class-specifiers.php).